# Java, enum with constructor

Tags: java, enums, refactoring

I'm refactoring some legacy system written in Java, and I came across a problem with an enum constructor.

I have an enum class like this (just an  example):

```
public enum Signal{
   ON(new InButton()),
   OFF(new OutButton())

   private final Button button;

   Signal(Button button) {
       this.button = button;
   }
}
```

InButton and OutButton extends the Button interface.

The enum values are accessed for the first time using Signal.Values() method.
(Also, in one of the Button method, I have a code that uses the enum, such as activateButton(Signal.ON))

While refactoring the code, I wanted to create a new constructor for Button that express it dependency, such as Button(String input).

The problem is that I don't know how to pass the new parameters to the enum button field.
What is the right way to deal with this situation?
Is this enum should be used at all?

---

Clarification after Jean Logeart question: `InButton` and `OutButton` also have a constructor with a `String` arguments.
I'd rather avoid it to be initialize to null because than it could create other problems.

Basically this question is how to mimic a=f(x) using java syntax. Most of the time I can do:

1. y = new x(); a = new f(y);
2. a = new f(new x());
3. a = new f(null); a.getF().setX(new x());

In this case I can't do it.

Comment: I would say that this part of the code doesn't need a refactor at all. It's an implementation of `Singleton` inside the `Signal` enum.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, Hi - It's more like the first option that Jean Logeart described in his answer, so a default constructor without values is not valid in InButton and OutButton anymore.

Comment: That's not a refactoring in your code, it's plain maintenance. And that's the obvious solution here.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I wanted to refactor the InButton and OutButton classes in order to express their dependencies and create testcases for them. Perhaps you right about the semantics, anyway it created a problem in the enum class ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest not having the enums know about the buttons at all. Just have them enumerate the possible signals, and put the job of mapping signal->button somewhere else:

```
Function<Signal, Button> signalToButton = ...
```

That will also make it easier to inject different buttons for testing; for instance, you can inject a mocked Button that confirms that it was our wasn't pressed.

As far as using that mapping in your code: you can "install" a mapping to some static field, or, better yet, provide it as a constructor argument to any code that needs it. Dependency injection is very helpful for the latter option, but that may be a bigger change.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable solution. I just hopped that there is a more elegant way to mimic a=f(g(x)) using java syntax.
Most of the time I can define y = new g(x) and than a = new f(y), or a = new f(new g(x)); in this case I can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Two main options.

First one, `InButton` and `OutButton` also have a constructor with a `String` argument in which case you need to provide a `String` when instanciating:

```
public class InButton extends Button {
    public InButton(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
// ...
public enum Signal{
    ON(new InButton("in"))
    // ...
}
```

Second option, `InButton` and `OutButton` are instanciated with a specific `String` in which case no refactoring is necessary in the `enum`:

```
public class InButton extends Button {
    public InButton() {
        super("in");   // default value
    }
}
// ...
public enum Signal{
    ON(new InButton())   // same as before
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The first option is correct, but this input string is not known in compile time, it's a parameter that the program initialize before accessing Signal.Values() - for example using a value from properties file.

Comment: What about defaulting to ``null`` and adding a setter?

Comment: It's a bit tricky, some methods in the buttons classes can be accessed by external clients in any time, meaning that the creation of the Button must be in one step, and I can't expose partial Button.